# Meteor package breaks bootstrap

Tags: node.js, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-meteor

In my angular-meteor project, I opted for using meteor's bootstrap package nemo64:bootstrap, for it's easy customization of the original bootstrap settings. However, when installing another meteor package for easy html text editor, the fraywing:text-angular..

When installed, the text-angular package installs twbs:bootstrap, which is another package to handle bootstrap, and this breaks most of my bootstrap javascript functions, because of the double call all of them recieve (one from the nemo64 and another form the twbs)..

I figured I could just uninstall the twbs:bootstrap package via `meteor remove twbs:bootstrap` but the command fails due to the package haven't been installed, because it comes bundled with the `fraywing:text-angular` package.

Is there any way I can remove that dependecy from text-angular, as I'm using nemo64's bootstrap package.

Thanks in advance.

This is the package list from meteor:

```
accounts-password             1.1.4  Password support for accounts
angular                       1.3.5* Everything you need to use AngularJS in your Meteor app
angular:angular-sanitize      1.5.0  AngularJS (official) release. For full solution: http://angular-meteor.com/
angularui:angular-ui-router   0.2.15  angular-ui-router (official): Flexible routing with nested views in AngularJS
check                         1.1.0  Check whether a value matches a pattern
email                         1.0.8  Send email messages
es5-shim                      4.1.14  Shims and polyfills to improve ECMAScript 5 support
fortawesome:fontawesome       4.5.0  Font Awesome (official): 500+ scalable vector icons, customizable via CSS, Retina friendly
fraywing:text-angular         1.3.11  A radically powerful Text-Editor/Wysiwyg editor for Angular.js!
jquery                        1.11.4  Manipulate the DOM using CSS selectors
less                          2.5.1  Leaner CSS language
meteor-base                   1.0.1  Packages that every Meteor app needs
mobile-experience             1.0.1  Packages for a great mobile user experience
mongo                         1.1.3  Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo over DDP
mquandalle:bower              1.5.2_1  Use Bower packages in your Meteor app
natestrauser:animate-css      3.4.0  Animate.css packaged for meteor
nemo64:bootstrap              3.3.5_2  Highly configurable bootstrap integration.
session                       1.1.1  Session variable
standard-minifiers            1.0.2  Standard minifiers used with Meteor apps by default.
timmyg:wow                    1.0.1  WOW css animations 
tmeasday:publish-counts       0.7.3  Publish the count of a cursor, in real time
tracker                       1.0.9  Dependency tracker to allow reactive callbacks
urigo:angular-blaze-template  0.3.0  Include Blaze templates in your angular-meteor application.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the package locally and modify it:  create a `packages` folder in root folder, clone the fraywing package into it from github then modify its dependencies in package.js to use the nemo package instead of twbs.

Meteor will automatically use your local packages over the one from the repository, the list command should show a little star next to the fraywing package to indicate it has picked up the local one. This would however mean the package would not update to the latest version with meteor update...